# How can we move our lips even though they don't have any bones?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology

How can we move our lips even though they don't have any bones?

We can move everything if it is attached to the bones. Example: Legs & Arms.

otherwise we can't move it.

Comment: Have you heard the term 'muscles'?

Comment: Yes. I heard it. How does it answer this question?

Comment: Muscles don't need to be attached to bones to function. Look at slugs.

Comment: @user47532 Tongue, eyelids, eyeballs, nostrils: do you have an idea about how we move them? Heart also "moves"! Please do some basic reading before asking a question.

Comment: @JM97 they are not bones. I was trying to get a point across that bones are not necessary for movement. It has already been said by others too. Muscles need to be attached to *something* to exert force but that need not be a bone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of the [Orbicularis oris muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbicularis_oris_muscle), it's a complex of muscles in the lips that encircles the mouth, It forms the greater part of the substance of the lips, lying between the skin and the mucus membrane, and extending from the edge of each lip to its root.

[image]